# Jquery Changing href from element. between multiple filters list

Tags: jquery, filter

I have this category filter

```
<nav id="categoriasLista">
<ul id="lista-classe">
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/dkbkbm">Dark Knight<br/>Blade Knight<br/>Blade Master</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/dwsmgm">Dark Wizard<br/>Soul Master<br/>Grand Master</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/femehe">Fairy Elf<br/>Muse Elf<br/>High Elf</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/mgdm">Magic Gladiator<br/>Duel Master</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/dlle">Dark Lord<br/>Lord Emporer</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/sumbsdm">Summoner<br/>B.Summoner<br/>Dimension Master</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro classe" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/classe/rffm">Rage Fighter<br/>Fist Master</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="lista-tipo">
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro tipo" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/tipo/armaShield">Armas</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro tipo" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/tipo/asa">Asas</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro tipo" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/tipo/acessorio">Acessorios</a></li>
    <li><a class="seletor-filtro tipo" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/tipo/set">Sets</a><br/></li>
</ul>
<ul id="lista-nivel">
    <a class="seletor-filtro nivel" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/nivel/full">Itens Full</a>
    <a class="seletor-filtro nivel" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/nivel/semi-full">Itens Semi-full</a>
</ul>
```

What i need to do is, when i click on any `<a>` element on the first `<ul>` get the href attr and put on the second list `<a>` tags the href. Let me explain better.
Something like this:
Click on first list element.
Then the second list would change the href attr, adding the first filter parameter.

```
<li><a class="seletor-filtro tipo" href="/navegarLoja/filtro/tipo/armaShield/classe/dkbkbm/">Armas</a></li>
```

any idea how i can build this "multiple filter"?basic i just need to change the href attr, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.newlink.net/")
```

and if you want to bind it to a click

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $(this).attr("href", "http://www.newlink.net/");
});
```